# Can A TeamSite Backing Store Data on Window Server migrate to TeamSite on Linux Server?

Tags: windows, linux, teamsite, interwoven, autonomy

I migrated TeamSite backing store data on windows server(d:\iw-store\default) to a TeamSite backing store area on linux server(/iw-store), 
I activated the migrated store, but /iwmnt/default/ path was missing.

Can A TeamSite Backing Store Data on Windows Server migrate to TeamSite on Linux Server?

win2003:TS6.7.2 -> RHEL5.3:TS6.7.2

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done because of the way that the backing store is implemented on the the two platforms.